# Page not found when opening link as new window

Tags: javascript, html, django

Getting the error message;

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/undefined
```

When I try and open a link as a new window on Django, this is the code I wrote;

```
<div class="panel panel-default curriculum open paper-shadow" data-z="0.5">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-gray" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#curriculum-5">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left">
                <span class="icon-block img-circle bg-indigo-300 half text-white"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></span>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="text-headline">Linear Algebra</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <span class="collapse-status collapse-open">Open</span>
            <span class="collapse-status collapse-close">Close</span>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group collapse in" id="curriculum-5">
            <div class="list-group-item media">
              <div class="media-left">
                <div class="text-crt">1.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle text-green-300"></i><a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs','MyWindow','width=600,height=300'); return false;">Click Here</a>Vectors and Spaces</a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-right">
                <div class="width-100 text-right text-caption">Estimated time: </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item media active">
              <div class="media-left">
                <div class="text-crt">2.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle text-blue-300"></i> Linear combinations and spans
              </div>
              <div class="media-right">
                <div class="width-100 text-right text-caption">Estimated time: </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The YouTube video opens in a new window, but I get the error message in my initial window, the one with my current project open

Comment: I cannot replicate the 404 using Firefox. Do you have another event listener somewhere updating the URL?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah, let me add more code to show you